# Python Script to get a web log URL IP

Tags: python, websocket, ip

Given a web log URL for instance https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/display-hostname-ip-address-python/ . How can i get the associated IP address using python Script. Have tried the following ,but its not working .

```
socket.gethostbyname("Url")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you **don't include** the `protocol` (`http`/`https`/`ftp`/etc...), i.e.:

## **Correct:**

```
print(socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com'))
#172.217.17.4
```

## **Incorrect**

```
print(socket.gethostbyname('https://www.google.com'))
# socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```